# Formatting columns when writing to csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write the following list of lists to columns in a .csv file, using Python.

```
writelist = [['MET            ', '===============', 'eT_miss_inv', 'eT_miss_lep', 'eT_miss_seed', 'met_avPt_seed'], ['Photon         ', '===============', 'pass1phtriggers', 'nPh', 'topoetcone40_1ph', 'ptvarcone20_1ph', 'pT_1ph', 'eta_1ph', 'phi_1ph', 'dPhi_1ph', 'dPhi_1ph1jet', 'phi_V', 'nbaselinePh', 'dphimin4_lep'], ['Weight         ', '===============', 'j1_bweight', 'j1_bweight', 'j1_bweight', 'j2_bweight', 'j2_bweight', 'j2_bweight', 'LeptonWeight', 'TriggerWeight'], ['HLT            ', '===============', 'HLT_g120_loose', 'HLT_g140_loose', 'HLT_e20_medium', 'HLT_2e17_loose', 'HLT_mu20_iloose_L1MU15', 'HLT_mu26', 'HLT_2mu6', 'HLT_mu50'], ['Truth          ', '===============', 'pT_1jet_truth'], ['Other          ', '===============', 'RG', 'nbjets_seed', 'mctcorr2b', 'E_V', 'pT_V', 'pT_1jet_seed', 'topness', 'centrality', 'btagzerolep_channel', 'allGhostGood', 'averageIntPerXingCorr', 'CoreFlag', 'btag0l_channel', 'sumet_refjet_seed', 'pT_2jet_seed', 'isTruthAnalysis', 'mctcorrjj', 'pass1Ltriggers', 'eta_V', 'pT_B']]
```

The first two elements of every sub-lists are decorative (title+separation). I'm trying to have columns evenly spaced with tabs, like so:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest
writelist = [['MET            ', '===============', 'eT_miss_inv', 'eT_miss_lep', 'eT_miss_seed', 'met_avPt_seed'], ['Photon         ', '===============', 'pass1phtriggers', 'nPh', 'topoetcone40_1ph', 'ptvarcone20_1ph', 'pT_1ph', 'eta_1ph', 'phi_1ph', 'dPhi_1ph', 'dPhi_1ph1jet', 'phi_V', 'nbaselinePh', 'dphimin4_lep'], ['Weight         ', '===============', 'j1_bweight', 'j1_bweight', 'j1_bweight', 'j2_bweight', 'j2_bweight', 'j2_bweight', 'LeptonWeight', 'TriggerWeight'], ['HLT            ', '===============', 'HLT_g120_loose', 'HLT_g140_loose', 'HLT_e20_medium', 'HLT_2e17_loose', 'HLT_mu20_iloose_L1MU15', 'HLT_mu26', 'HLT_2mu6', 'HLT_mu50'], ['Truth          ', '===============', 'pT_1jet_truth'], ['Other          ', '===============', 'RG', 'nbjets_seed', 'mctcorr2b', 'E_V', 'pT_V', 'pT_1jet_seed', 'topness', 'centrality', 'btagzerolep_channel', 'allGhostGood', 'averageIntPerXingCorr', 'CoreFlag', 'btag0l_channel', 'sumet_refjet_seed', 'pT_2jet_seed', 'isTruthAnalysis', 'mctcorrjj', 'pass1Ltriggers', 'eta_V', 'pT_B']]
with open("result.csv","w+") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')
for values in izip_longest(*writelist):
    writer.writerow(values)
```

However, as can be checked by opening `result.csv`, the alignment isn't coming out right. How can I fix it?

Comment: A csv file is **not** a fixed size columns file...  You are using the wrong tool here

Comment: @SergeBallesta Any suggestions what I should use then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `str.format` for padding and justification of text.

https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings